# Gay Marriage in the EU

Tags: eu

I am an Indian passport holder. I'm in love with a Luxembourg citizen. We have known each other for 2 years. We both are gay. We are planning to get married in a country where gay marriage is legal. The problem for us is, I applied for a Schengen tourist visa and got rejected twice. Can you please help us? Is there any marriage visa in the EU or Luxembourg?

Comment: Does your fiancé live in Luxembourg?  The process of joining him may depend on whether he lives there or in another EU country.

Comment: Did you apply for the visa in Luxembourg? If you are looking for a straightforward place to get married in, I was married in Denmark (I was on a tourist visa) and it was a wonderful experience. Denmark has gay marriage as well.

Comment: Don't try Germany. First, one of you must be resident. Second, marriage must be legal according to German law, and according to the law of the parties getting married. So if you can't get married in your own country, you can't get married in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Luxembourg has recognised same sex marriage since 2015 so you should be able to get a marriage visa on the same basis as a hetrosexual couple.